# Change EUID and EGID of a given process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

Using a kernel module in linux can we change the `EUID` and `EGID` of a given process? Basically we have been provided with PID and I want to change the `EUID` and `EGID` of the given process using a kernel module. It won't allow us to change `p->cred->euid` directly as it is read only. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you have a look at how it's changed by the seteuid system call? Of course, that changes the value of the current process, but may give some idea.